# Convolution Integral and dummy variable

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have no idea how to find a dummy variable or start with this problem. I'm given the function:

$$
{\rm g}\left(\, x\,\right)
=\int^{x}_{0}\left(\, x - t\,\right){\rm f}\left(\,t\,\right)\,{\rm d}t
$$

1. Compute ${\rm g}\left(\,x\,\right)$ assuming ${\rm f}\left(\, x\,\right) = x$.
2. Second, completely independent of $a$ find the dummy variable.

Comment: Does a) mean we can assume $f(t)=t$, or is that not true?

Comment: @HDE it does not specify that. I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Since f(x)=x, then f(t)=t.

$$
g(x)=\int_0^x (x-t)t (dt)
g(x)=\int_0^x (xt-t^2) (dt)= \int_0^x xt (dt) -\int_0^x t^2(dt)=(xt^2/2)|_0^x-(t^3/3)|_0^x
g(x)=x^3/2-x^3/3=(3x^3-2x^3)/6=x^3/6
$$

I don't know what is a dummy variable :(

Comment: I guess t is the dummy variable because it doesn't show up in the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RandomGuy. In convolution the dummy variable is the one that is always integrated out. In what i've learned from taking a signals course the convolution shifts one of the signals using a dummy variable and then uses integration to "detect" where the two functions overlap, because in essence integration is addition.

Imagine the two signals on the same graph. Move one signal and every time it overlaps(area) with the second signal that means whatever you have as an integrand exists. Then add up all of these integrands for every overlap that occurs.